# laravel 5.8 migration foreign key problems

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, database-migration

Ok I'm stuck.  Seems like a simple thing and I've seen others have issues as well.  I'm using the latest version 5.8.x. I have no issues creating the tables but when I start with a fresh database and add the foreign keys I get error-

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `apbase`.`#sql-546_1a14` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `apconfig`
>   add constraint `apconfig_apevent_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`apevent_id`) references `apevents` (`id`))

I have renamed migration files so any nitration with a foreign key is migrated after the reference table. The migration files were created using artisan.

```
Schema::create('apevents', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 200);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('apconfig', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('apevent_id');
        $table->foreign('apevent_id')->references('id')->on('apevents');
        $table->string('name', 200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `apevent_id` in `apconfig` table should be

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('apevent_id');
```